# Detect if method closest () is supported

Tags: javascript, closest

I would like to find out if the method closest () is supported and if necessary (IE 11) use an alternative in the following form:

```
ancestor = ('closest' in document.documentElement) ? element.closest  (selector) : element.parentElement;
```

The consoles of my browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, IE 11 - WIN 10) return 'true' or 'false' as expected.

Is this solution a clean solution or are there any pitfalls that I did not consider ?

Comment: Uh, if the method is not available, it doesn't use  the `selector` but just get the parent element? So I wouldn't even consider this to be a "solution".

Answer (score 0):

Better use a polyfill that checks if the methods exist and, if not, adds an equivalent to an Objects prototype. Then use the method in all browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

[Lets see what MDN says about this:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill)

> For browsers that do not support Element.closest(), but carry support
>   for element.matches() (or a prefixed equivalent, meaning IE9+), a
>   polyfill exists:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
                              Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}

if (!Element.prototype.closest) {
  Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
    var el = this;

    do {
      if (el.matches(s)) return el;
      el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
    } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1);
    return null;
  };
}
```

so your approach is right. Please [consult mdn for further info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill)